# "error C2065 : TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL : undeclared identifier"

Tags: visual-c++

I want to create a low integrity process using Visual Studio 2005 .I am using the code for CreateLowProcess() given here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx .

But while compiling, the code gives errors like :

```
error C2065 : 'TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL' : undeclared identifier
error C2065 : 'SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY' : undeclared identifier
error C2065 : 'TokenIntegrityLevel' : undeclared identifier
```

I have tried including "Windows.h" both before and after "stdafx.h". What might be the problem  ? 
Do I need to include some other headers as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These items were introduced for Windows Vista and the SDK included with VS 2005 is a pre-Vista version.  You'll either need to configure your project to use an appropriate SDK or use a newer version of Visual C++ (2008 or later).